# PHP sessions ending when form submitted

Tags: php

I have a problem when I submit a form on a page which causes the session to end and the user has to log back in. I have spent hours trying to sort this and not getting anywhere with it!
This is the code from the page where form is -

```
<?php
session_start(); /// initialize session
$title = 'Month Edit';
include("passwords.php");
$user_email = check_logged(1, $dbc);
?>
```

the form code is just

The passwords.php page is

```
<?php
require ('ct_db.php');//This is the database info
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);

while($check_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $this_us = $check_row['user'];
  $this_ps = $check_row['pass'];
  $USERS[$this_us] = $this_ps;
}

function check_logged($page, $dbc)
{ 
     global $_SESSION, $USERS;
     if (!array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS))
      { 
        header("Location: login.php"); 
     }
     else
     {
        $this_user = $_SESSION["logged"];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$this_user'";
        $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $user_email = $row2['email'];
        $user_permission = $row2['permissions'];
        if($page == 3 && ($user_permission=="admin" || $user_permission=="user"))
        {
         header("Location: login.php"); 
        }
      else
      {
      if($page == 2 && $user_permission=="user")
      {
      header("Location: login.php"); 
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<div id="logged_in">';
        echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ax" value="out"> '; 
        echo 'Logged in as <span style="color:blue">'.$_SESSION["logged"]."</span> ";
        echo 'email '.$user_email.' ';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Logout" id="log_out"/></div><br>'; 
        return $user_email;
      }
    }
    }
}; 
?>
```

I also have a login page which includes the following

```
<?php
session_start();
$title = 'login';
require ('ct_db.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);

 while($check_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
  $this_us = $check_row['user'];
  $this_ps = $check_row['pass'];
  $USERS[$this_us] = $this_ps;
  }


function check_logged($page)
{ 
     global $_SESSION, $USERS; 
     if (!array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS))
      { 
        header("Location: login.php"); 
     }
     else
     {
        $this_user = $_SESSION["logged"];
        require ('ct_db.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$this_user'";
        $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $user_email = $row2['email'];
        $user_permission = $row2['permissions'];
        if($page == 3 && ($user_permission=="admin" || $user_permission=="user"))
        {
         header("Location: login.php"); 
        }
      else
      {
      if($page == 2 && $user_permission=="user")
      {
      header("Location: login.php");
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<div id="logged_in">';
        echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ax" value="out"> '; 
        echo 'Logged in as <span style="color:blue">'.$_SESSION["logged"]."</span> ";
        echo 'email '.$user_email.' ';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Logout" id="log_out"/>'; 
        return $user_email;
        }
        }
    }
}; 

require ('ct_db.php');
if ($_POST["ac"]=="log")
 { /// do after login form is submitted  
     if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) /// check if submitted  username and password exist in $USERS array 
     { 
          $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"];
          $_SESSION["email"] = 'email address';
          echo 'email = '.$_SESSION["email"];
     } 
     else
     {
          echo 'Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.';
     };
};

if ($_POST["ax"]=="out")
 { /// do after login form is submitted
     if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) /// check if submitted  username and password exist in $USERS array 
     {
          session_destroy();
          echo 'You are logged out';
          //header("Location: login.php");
          die;
     }
}; 

if (array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) //// check if user is logged or not  
{ 
     echo "You are logged in.";
     echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ax" value="out"> '; 
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Logout" />'; 
     echo '</form>';
     header("Location: mainPage3.php"); 

      //// if user is logged show a message  
} 
else 
{ //// if not logged show login form 
    echo '<div id="login">';
    echo '<h1>Connectivity</h1>';
    echo 'Please login<br><br>';
    echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> '; 
    echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br>'; 
    echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br>'; 
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
    echo '</form>'; 
    echo '</div><!--End login-->';
}; 
?>
```

In my attempts to solve the problem, I have changed and added a lot of code and I'm sure it is more complex than it should be. I can move from page to page withing the site without being logged out and can refresh the page containing the form with any problem. But if i press submit, I go back to the login page. 
The only thing I can think that may be a clue is that the user info is in a different database to the site info but I have checked to make sure I have the correct code for each one.
Any help gratefully received.

Comment: You don't need `global` declaration for superglobals like `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Why do you store all usernames and associated passwords in an array? Just query on the username and password to verify existence.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see only two kind of submit buttons in your code Login and Logout (twice) and both the forms have action = login.php.

When clicking on the logout button the session is destroyed via the code.
When an already logged in user clicks on login button (assuming that the button is visible) it will set the values in the post as blank values and the user will be redirected to the login.php page as the validation will throw logged == false.

I have not tested your code but apparently this seems to be the problem.